# Executing two different MySQL queries in a single class of JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

When I try to run this, it says that "Operation cannot be run as the resultset has ended."

```
public void multiplequeries() throws Exception{
    //try{
    //This will load the MySQL Driver, each DB has its own driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //Setup the connection with the database
    connect = (Connection) DriverManager
            .getConnection("....these details are correct....");

    try(Statement stmt = connect.createStatement())
    {
        /*COUNT(*) should be used instead of * but it is not necessary*/

        String query = "select * from course where dept_name='Comp. Sci.'";
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        int i=0;

        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            i=i+1;
        }

        System.out.println("The Total number of courses are: " + i);
    }
}
```

Now I have another query that needs to be run. It uses different tables and the result is also different.

```
select ID, COUNT(DISTINCT course_id) as coursecount 
from teaches as t natural join instructor as i
where i.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'
group by ID
```

It returns number of courses taught by the instructors.

The schema's are as follows:

```
course (**course_id**, title, dept_name, credits)
teaches (**ID**, **course_id**, **sec_id**, **semester**, **year**)
instructor (**ID**, name, dept_name, salary)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I am almost certain the error doesn't come from the code you've posted.

Answer (score -1):

Close ResultSet before execute next query

```
public void multiplequeries() throws Exception{
//try{
//This will load the MySQL Driver, each DB has its own driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//Setup the connection with the database
connect = (Connection) DriverManager
        .getConnection("....these details are correct....");

try(Statement stmt = connect.createStatement())
{
    /*COUNT(*) should be used instead of * but it is not necessary*/

    String query = "select * from course where dept_name='Comp. Sci.'";
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    int i=0;

    while (resultSet.next())
    {
        i=i+1;
    }
    resultSet.close();
    System.out.println("The Total number of courses are: " + i);
}
}
```

Comment: What will this change?

Comment: I am closing the whole class right? Now to execute the second one, I have to declare a new class. I don't want that. It says "Operation is not allowed after the ResultSet is closed". What do I do now?

Comment: first close result set before
   System.out.println("The Total number of courses are: " + i);

Comment: Why would OP need to do that?